# Angular FormGroup in Storybook: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm work with angular and storybook. I have a FormGroup and FormArray in my model but they are not working with storybook.

a.stories.ts ->

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, Story } from '@storybook/angular';

export default {
    title: 'Example/A',
    component: AComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
            ],
            providers: [],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<AComponent> = (args: AComponent) => ({
    props: args,
});

export const Costs = Template.bind({});
Costs.args = {
    model: {
        questions: [
            {
                ...,
                "question": "lorem ipsum",
                "formGroup": new FormGroup({
                    answers: new FormArray([
                        new FormGroup({
                            "Q020_A001": new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
                            "Q020_A002": new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
                        }),
                    ]),
                }),
                "answers": [
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A001",
                    },
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A002",
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

I get an error in storybook ->

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FormGroup'
    |     property 'controls' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'answers' -> object with constructor 'FormArray'
    --- property '_parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

It works if "formGroup" is empty. ->

```
            "formGroup": new FormGroup({
            }),
```

But if "formGroup" is not empty, it won't work. ->

```
        "formGroup": new FormGroup({
            asd: new FormControl(''),
        }),
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new AStoryComponent.

```
// a-story.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'a-component-story',
    template: `<a-component [model]="model"></a-component>`,
})
export class AStoryComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() model!: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // Converts the "formGroup" property I specified in a.stories.ts to the real formGroup object.
        convertStoryModelToRealModel(this.model);
    }

}


// a.stories.ts

import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, Story } from '@storybook/angular';

export default {
    title: 'Example/A',
    component: AStoryComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            declarations: [AStoryComponent, AComponent],
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
            ],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<AStoryComponent> = (args: AStoryComponent) => ({
    props: args,
});

export const Costs = Template.bind({});
Costs.args = {
    model: {
        questions: [
            {
                ...,
                "question": "lorem ipsum",
                "formGroup": {
                    answers: [
                        {
                            "Q020_A001": [null, [Validators.required]],
                            "Q020_A002": [null, [Validators.required]],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                "answers": [
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A001",
                    },
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A002",
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    } as any,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for every `args` you provided to Storybook, SB gonna call `JSON.stringify`. This design is required because SB also use your `args` at runtime and allow you to change value.

In your case, you create a Reactive forms model which cause the object to be not able to convert to string by `JSON.stringify`.

To fix it, you need to:

1. Provide args to SB as raw data only
2. Change logic in your `AComponent` to create model from data provided above

Sample code:

```
/// a.stories.ts
Costs.args = {
    model: {
        questions: [
            {
                ...,
                "question": "lorem ipsum",
                "formGroup": {
                    answers: [
                        {
                            "Q020_A001": null,
                            "Q020_A002": null,
                        }),
                    ]),
                },
                "answers": [
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A001",
                    },
                    {
                        ...,
                        "answerCode": "Q020_A002",
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

```
/// A.component.ts

export class AComponent {
  @Input() model;

  constructor() {
     // create your reactive forms here with data from model
     this.form = new FormGroup(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that storybook uses `JSON.stringify`. But this solution doesn't solve my problem. Is not suitable for the structure.

Comment: Here is a thread on storybook github discussing this issue.  https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/15602

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a very easy way to avoid this error with pretty much no efforts. This also keep working valueChanges behaviours.

Storybook tries to stringify any args you pass to a component. We can just tell our formGroups to be stringified by our rules.

By setting [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) on our objects, we can prevent Storybook from trying to serialize a circular structure.

```
const MY_FORM = new FormGroup({
    a: new FormControl('A'),
    b: new FormControl('B'),
})

// Tell JSON.stringify to serialize it as null > No circular dependency
MY_FORM['toJSON'] = () => null; 

export const FormStory: Story = {
    name: 'FormStory',
    args: {
        form: MY_FORM
    },
};
```

Note that this would work for ANY object that circles when stringified