# Is it possible to Mock an Angular FormGroup by creating a Provider?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mocking, angular-reactive-forms

I want to create a "Testbed" for storybook and embed a component which requires a FormGroup on a parent DOM element.
Is it possible to skip the template and pass all required elements to the reactive form control by providing an Injectable?

**Before:**

```html
<div [formGroup]='formGroupA'>
   <app-example-field formControlName='example'></app-example-field>
</div>
```

```js
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
// e.g.
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
  example: new FormControl('')
});
```

**After:** Direct template

```html
<app-example-field formControlName='example'></app-example-field>
```

```js
import { FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Storybook (should work in the same way as a standalone Module + Component) ... 
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        MyExampleModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        // What to put here?
      ]
    })
  ],
```

Without a valid `formGroup` the angular directive `formControlName` throws an error:
`ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`

Any idea? How to pass this issue?

Comment: Otherwise I have to go for the Component solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895602/5842853

Comment: <app-example-field is child component or an input-field?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed `app-example-field` is a custom form control (component with value accessor)